# How to install bind dns server and apache web server in ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, bind

Hello everyone I'm new to this ask ubuntu can anyone guide me on how to install bind and apache in Ubuntu? I'm new to Ubuntu since I'm using windows, I need this to complete my project in Linux.

Comment: You will need more experience to set-up something that is secure and maintainable. I suggest you to hire a sysadmin for the server if you are incapable. There are plenty of guides on installing bind and Apache, what is unclear?

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought my question is quite unclear or something? but I was just asking for proper directions to where and how I can learn to install these servers since i'm using windows so ubuntu is quite new to me also the way the commands and stuff but thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- You can open some package manager like: **Muon Package Manager**, ..... then easily search two names , **apache2** and **bind9**. Check and tick all you need and then press install.

2- The easiest way using terminal is:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2

sudo apt-get install bind9
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apache2 bind9 bind9-doc bind9utils` should do it. Note that the last two packages are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Apache and BIND packages using the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 bind9
```